# Writing to io.BytesIO in csv fails in python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, csv, bytesio

I am trying to write python 2/3 compatible code to write strings to csv file object. This code:

```
line_as_list = [line.encode() for line in line_as_list]
writer_file =  io.BytesIO()
writer = csv.writer(writer_file, dialect=dialect, delimiter=self.delimiter)
for line in line_as_list:
    assert isinstance(line,bytes)
    writer.writerow(line)
```

Gives this error on Python3:

```
>           writer.writerow(line)
E           TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

But assert has no problem with the type, so why is `csv` creating an error?

Can't I use `BytesIO` only for both Python 2 and 3? Where is the problem here?

Comment: @tdelaney What I meant was I am not sure whether StringIO and BytesIO will give the same representation for source text (probably in  `utf-8`). Thats why I am trying to use the same output object type.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Python3 `csv.writer` expects a file-like object opened in text mode.
In Python2, `csv.writer` expects a file-like object opened in binary mode.

Therefore, in Python3, use `io.StringIO`, while in Python2 use `io.BytesIO`:

```
import io
import csv
import sys
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3

line_as_list = [u'foo', u'bar']
encoding = 'utf-8'

if PY3:
    writer_file =  io.StringIO()
else:
    writer_file =  io.BytesIO()
    line_as_list = [line.encode(encoding) for line in line_as_list]

writer = csv.writer(writer_file, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
writer.writerow(line_as_list)
content = writer_file.getvalue()

if PY3:
    content = content.encode(encoding)

print(type(content))
print(repr(content))
```

---

In Python3 the code above prints

```
<class 'bytes'>
b'foo,bar\r\n'
```

In Python2 the code above prints

```
<type 'str'>
'foo,bar\r\n'
```

Comment: That's a good workaround, but any idea why the error asks for 'bytes', when str *is* a byte format?

Comment: I believe that error is coming from the `BytesIO` object -- it is complaining that it was passed a `str` when it expected `bytes`. In Python3 a `str` is not a "byte format". A unicode `str` is a sequence of code points.

Comment: But I passed a  str.encode() object, effectively a bytes object. Then where is the problem? This error says that `str` was passed, when it wasn't (just talking about Python 3).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error you posted so this is just a guess. What is `self.delimiter`? Could it have been a `str`?

Comment: Yeah, that may be it, though after encoding the delimiter it says that 'the delimiter must be string, not bytes'.

Comment: In Python3 the `csv` module wants unicode `str`s. In Python2 the `csv` module wants byte `str`s.

Comment: Yeah, the `delimiter` *has* to be `unicode` in Python3, and so it doesn't work with `bytes` at all.