# Bytes(str?) to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've looked at the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974199/writing-to-io-bytesio-in-csv-fails-in-python3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305926/python-csv-string-to-array). But they have either been trying to write bytes to a CSV or saving a CSV from a string but I'm trying to connect trying writing bytes to a CSV.

I have a blob of `bytes` and if I do `type(bytes)` I get `<class 'bytes'>` but when I try to write to a csv I get an error

```
(Pdb) f = open('/Users/minhmai/test.csv', 'wb+')
(Pdb) writer = csv.writer(f)
(Pdb) writer.writerow(bytes)
*** TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'


(Pdb) f = open('/Users/minhmai/test.csv', 'wb+')
(Pdb) writer = csv.writer(f)
(Pdb) writer.writerows(bytes)
*** _csv.Error: iterable expected, not int
```

However If I do this, I just get a number but it's not really saved to a CSV.

```
(Pdb) wfile = io.StringIO()
(Pdb) writer = csv.writer(wfile)
(Pdb) writer.writerow(bytes)
```

And example of what my data(`bytes`) look like is this

```
b'Date,ID,Amount\r\n2018-1-1,1,25\r\n2018-1-2,2,3\r\n2018-1-1,2,3\r\n`
```

Ideally this would result in a header row and 3 rows

Comment: Looks like you overwrote the standard class name `bytes` with some value. Do you have a line `bytes=...` somewhere in your program? Change the variable name to something else!

Comment: Either lose the `b` (*binary* - which makes the content - raw bytes) from `wb+` when opening files, either use `.encode()` when writing strings.

Comment: In Python 3 `csv.writer` expects a file (like) object opened in *text mode*, with `newline=''`. Your `TypeError` is a result of not honouring that; though you'd try and pass a list of `bytes()` objects, you'd get a *string* row that contained string representations of those objects (the `b'...'` representation).

Comment: I think @Ilja Everilä is exactli right—sounds like the cause and the way to fix the issue.

Comment: Hey @DYZ. the `bytes` was just an example, in my work, it is named something else but the error is the same

@IljaEverilä I've tried doing what you did but it turns out to be a row full of numbers?

Comment: That we cannot help you with, since you've not provided a [mcve].

Comment: @IljaEverilä updated. I have created a test snippet.

Comment: That's a bit confusing. From the looks of it your "snippet" is a bytes object that contains encoded csv text already. Why are you trying to pass that to a writer?